# Converting hair particles to only one mesh to avoid Blender crashing

Tags: modifiers, particles

I have a tree that is emitting 32,000 planes that are textured as leaves.  I need to get all of these to be one single object, however if I click 'convert' in the modifiers section, Blender becomes unusable by trying to create 32,000 different objects.  Is there another option or script I could use to convert a particle system to a single object?